# Drawing the vertical line in linear regression

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw the vertical line, for example, x=8.74, but it does not do it. I get this message:

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`.
Caused by error:
! object 'y' not found

Attached code and image.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point(col = "blue")+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x, se = F, col = "black")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title= element_text(size = 14),
        legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "Y sobre X")+
  annotate('text', x = median(df$x), y = max(df$y)+sd(df$y)/2, label = label_y,
           family= theme_get()$text[["family"]],
           size= theme_get()$text[["size"]]/2.5,
           fontface="italic")

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point(col = "blue")+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= x~y, se = F, col = "black")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.title= element_text(size = 14),
        legend.position = "none")+
  labs(title = "X sobre Y")+
  annotate('text', x = median(df$x), y = max(df$y)+sd(df$y)/2, label = label_x,
           family= theme_get()$text[["family"]],
           size= theme_get()$text[["size"]]/2.5,
           fontface="italic")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See `geom_vline()` in the ggplot2 package.

Comment: Should your `geom_smooth()` formula in `p2` be x~y or y~x?

Comment: it's generally considered best practice to leave your question close to its original form; you can edit to add clarifying statements, but incorporating parts of answers is not generally helpful

Comment: I take your comment into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have constructed an example where the slope of the regression of Y on X is *exactly* zero; is that true? The basic problem is that (even though it was a clever thing to try) you can't just invert the order of the regression formula to get a regression of X on Y rather than a regression of Y on X. As @Dave2E says,you could use `+ geom_vline(xintercept = mean(df$x))` to add a vertical line explicitly.

If your slope were not *exactly* zero, you could run the regression outside of `ggplot2`, compute the corresponding slope and intercept for a Y-vs-X line, and add it to the plot use `geom_abline()` (but this won't work if the X-vs-Y slope is 0, because the Y-vs-X slope will be infinite ...)

```r
## x = a + b*y -> y = x/a-b/a
m <- lm(x ~ y, data = df)
a <- coef(m)[1]; b <- coef(m)[2]
ggplot(...) + geom_abline(intercept = -b/a, slope = 1/a)
```

To add a vertical line that covers only the Y-range of the data, something like

```r
+ geom_segment(x=mean(df$x), xend = mean(df$x), y = min(df$y), yend = max(df$y))
```

should work ...

Comment: I have added geom_vline(xintercept = mean(df$x),size = 0.85)

Comment: How can I make the straight line shorter?

Comment: Perfect. It works.